# string format not working for DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Put folloing xaml for Currency formating, but not working. Why?

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Header="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=Amount: {0:C}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Amount` is in numeric type. `Strings` won't format.