# Set format to the data that presented in DataGrid -WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, format

I want to set format to columns of the DataGrid in **xaml**, the columns contain double data.

Until now I did it in the code as follows:

```
string format = "{0:F3}";
double nExm= 4.24;
string newExm= string.Format(format, nExm);
```

The DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Exm}" Binding="{Binding Exm}"></DataGridTextColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

newExm it varies that is included within the class X that contains the list that binding to the DataGrid

X Class:

private string exm;

```
    public string Exm
    {
        get { return exm; }
        set
        {
            exm= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Exm");
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to set the format via XAML?  (I want to turn variable to double and set the format on columns)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465348/string-format-not-working-for-datagridtextcolumn 
the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StringFormat` on your `Binding` to format it:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

`Binding="{Binding YourDoublePropertyHere, StringFormat=F3}"`

If `StringFormat` doesn't give you all your formatting needs (in this case it should be adequate), or you have more sophisticated conversion logic then you could write a `Converter` to massage the data.

- http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set `StringFormat` in XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding paymentAmount, StringFormat={0:C2}}"/>
```

[Here](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2010/05/28/silverlight-4-binding-and-stringformat-in-xaml/) is a great article about that